# Why would a Guid not be recognized unless created by NewGuid()?

Tags: powershell-3.0, dynamics-crm-2015

I have some code that calls the `Set-CrmRecord` cmdlet for the **Microsoft.Xrm.Data.PowerShell**. It is returning an `InvalidCastException`. The trouble is that I can find nothing that isn't the correct type. Here's the code:

```
    Set-CrmRecord -conn $conn -EntityLogicalName $entityName -Id $id -Fields $entity -Upsert
```

The id must be a guid. When I suspend the script and type `$id.GetType()` it returns that it is a guid. Fields must be a hash table, which `GetType()` confirms it is. Same with the connection and the entity name. I've also checked the hashtable, shown below:

```
$id = [guid]::Parse($_.Queue)
$entity = @{
    "queueid" = $id;
    "name" = $_.Name
}
```

The queueid is a Guid and name is string. So, it appears that everything is correct. So, two questions:

1. Is something betting wrapped into a PSObject or not getting parsed when I think it is?
2. Is there any way to figure the actual value causing the issue?

#### Update

If I suspend during a debug session, I can create a GUID and the hashtable and call the cmdlet and it succeeds.

#### Update 2

I've determined that the issue is with the -Id argument. The only way it works is if I use `[guid]::NewGuid()`. If I use either `[guid]::new('...')` or `[guid]::Parse('...')`, it doesn't work and gives me a cast exception. Casting also does not work with these other options. I.e. `[guid]$id` when the id is made with either of the other two types doesn't work.

Also note that the guid passed in to the hashtable works in all cases.

What is the difference between these calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like `Set-CrmRecord` wants you to specify the record's Id in the -Fields hashtable.

Example:

Create a new account using upsert

```
$id = [Guid]::NewGuid() 
$entity = @{"name"="Foo Bar"}
$newid = Set-CrmRecord -conn $con -EntityLogicalName account -id $id -Fields $entity -Upsert
```

Now update it with upsert

```
$entity = @{"name"="Foo Bar Baz"}
Set-CrmRecord -conn $con -EntityLogicalName account -id $newid -Fields $entity -Upsert
```

You can specify the -id parameter as either a Guid object or just the guid's text representation.